# Changing MongoDB Isolation level when Mongo Sessions involved

Tags: mongodb, transactions, isolation-level

Whats is the default Isolation level for MongoDB4.0 when transactions are used.

One Document say READ UNCOMMITTED is default isolation level.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/

Another document says snapshot is default isolation level when transaction are used.
https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/06/25/mongodb-transactions-your-very-first-transaction-with-mongodb-4-0/

Which one is correct? Is it possible to change it ?

Comment: Did you mean "read uncommitted" is the default isolation level as per https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/ ?

Comment: Sorry, Yes. I meant READ UNCOMMITTED

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoDB allows the client to determine the required isolation level depending on requirements via a combination of write concern, read concern, and the use of sessions.

With regard to transactions (which requires the use of sessions), the default isolation is snapshot.

Read uncommitted is the default isolation level *without* the use of sessions, as per [Read Isolation, Consistency, and Recency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#read-uncommitted).

It is possible to customize the read & write concerns of a transaction. See:

- [Transactions and Read Concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-and-read-concern)
- [Transactions and Write Concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-and-write-concern)

Unless you have a specific use case requiring specific isolation levels, it's best to leave this setting as default.

Comment: Please be aware that `snapshot` isolation is the *best* isolation that could be achieved using MongoDB transactions, **but not with the default settings!** To achieve it, you must set `readConcern=snapshot` and `writeConcern=majority` *on connection string/session/transaction* (but not on database/collection/operation as under a transaction database/collection/operation concern settings are ignored). See https://jepsen.io/analyses/mongodb-4.2.6